# Is there a way to connect SymPy symbolic differentiation with SciPy's Quad Integration package?

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, derivative, quad

I just recently learned how to integrate a two-variable function using SciPy's quad integration, with respect to just one variable. For instance, say we have a function f(x,y). I integrated with respect to x, in order to get f(y). I then plotted f(y) vs a NumPy array of y values. No problem here. However, I now would like to multiply my original integrand by a Jacobian Matrix (where each function in the respective entry of the Jacobian is also as a function of x and y).

The problem that I can't quite conceptualize now, is how to incorporate partial differentiation into my original code --- which very cleanly integrated my initial two-variable function. I am aware that SymPy is a great option for symbolic integration, but I could not figure out how to evaluate the Jacobian (due to the fact that this requires derivatives) in a way that would be compatible with it's result being multiplied by a separate function, and then integrating that product. Is there a form of **lambdify** , that instead of converting my SymPy functions to their NumPy counterparts, it converts SymPy functions to ones that are usable in SciPy's quad integration? Or is their another common practice?

```
from sympy import symbols, diff
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## define f(x,y) function *** BUT INTEGRATING dx ***
## where the bounds are as a function of y ***
## SciPy and NumPy are used in these steps

def example(y):
    return lambda x: (x * y)

def example_integral(y):
    return quad(example(y), 0, y, args=())


## F(y) = (y^3) / 2

print('F(y) --> F(4) = (4^3)/2 = ',example_integral(4)[0])
print('Integration works')


## Plotting f(y) vs. y
## This graph should follow cubic power
example_range = np.linspace(-11,10,20)
example_array = []

for i in example_range:
    example_array.append(example_integral(i)[0])

plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))    
plt.plot(example_range,example_array)
plt.title("Example Plot of original integrated function\nF(y) vs y")
plt.show()
```

```
## Here I will differentiate two separate functions for the Jacobian
## SymPy is used in these following steps
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
f = (2*x*(y**2)) + y**3
g = x/y

df_dx = diff(f, x)
df_dy = diff(f, y)
dg_dx = diff(g, x)
dg_dy = diff(g, y)

## I compute the Jacobian here
jacobian = (df_dy * dg_dx) - (df_dx * dg_dy)
print("The resulting Jacobian is: ", jacobian)
```

Per the suggestions, I included example code that explains best what my predicament is. Should this not abide by the "minimal example" guidelines, please comment and I will fix this. As you can see, in the first block, I used SciPy and NumPy to integrate and plot my original function. In the second block, I used SymPy to differentiate two separate functions and to compute the Jacobian. **Ultimately, I would like to multiply my resulting Jacobian (in the second block) by my original function (in the first block). After I have this new function (the product of the two), I would like to simply preform the same integration procedure.** Attached here --> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AM4i.png) is a screenshot of the error message I receive when I try to run this idea (this was expected). Please let me know if I can do anything to better explain this. Thank you!

Comment: I find it really difficult to discern what steps happen in SymPy and which should happen elsewhere. It would also help if you can produce an artificial [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that focusses on the translation you want to make, i.e., that somehow generates a comparable input and describes what you want the output to be. Please [edit] your question to address this.

Comment: Some actual code would help.  Start with a reproducible example of the quad that works for you.  Then as much of sympy link as you can.  A good answer will have a working example/proof.  The more you provide up front the easier it is to develop an answer.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I edited my original question, and provided a minimal example. Thank you and I hope this helps!

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your input! I added example code to my original question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can only make a wild guess that SymPy’s [`ufuncify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/numeric-computation.html#ufuncify) will help you. It translates SymPy expression to vectorised NumPy [ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html), which can be applied in a vectorised manner. Thus it can also be used by SciPy’s quadrature routines.

Comment: scipy.integrate.quad` doesn't do anything "vectorized" - it takes scalar function.

Comment: `scipy.integrate.quad` doesn’t, but `scipy.integrate.quadrature` does.

Comment: [quadpy.quad](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy/) also does. :)